# Woocommerce custom field search in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I have added a custom field with search to the General tab in Woocommerce Product, when I try to search it shows me products, I would like the search to conduct on a Custom Post Type I created called Authors rather than search in products.

[image]

Basically, is it possible to connect a Product to a Custom Post Type?
I am selling Books and would like that every (Book)Product will have a field saying who the Author is.

As for authors, every author will be extended according to Book author details such as: profile picture, description, links, social etc.

The idea is to be able to show a list of authors (just like a tag cloud).

Am I off on the way to implement this? is there a better way?

Thanks